# Facebook Send button dialog does not display fully

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

The dialog after clicking the Send button of Facebook seems to be truncated. I use this code to add the button to content.php of a WordPress site. The parents div display completely but this child div doesn't.

```
<div class="fb-send"></div>
```

[Picture of the dialog - Click here to see (I am a newbie here so I can't post  picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dLP5.png)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#flyout